# Left join query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following query

```
SELECT    table1.*, 
      table2.status
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid
WHERE     table2.transactionid IS NULL   --Doesn't exist in table2
OR        table2.status = 2
```

It returns me the table1 row if there isn't any row under the same transactionid in table2 or there is a row but it has status = 2 (error)

Now i need to modify it to don't return any table1 rows if there is a row with the same transactionid and status = 1 (completed) in table2

So, there can be multiple error rows but if there is one that is completed then i shouldn't get any result

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Sample data would further clarify your question.

Comment: Yeah, I always struggle with the concept of an OUTER JOIN with an OR condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Not exists` comes to mind:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2
                  WHERE t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid AND
                        t2.status = 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'NOT IN'

SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.transactionid   NOT IN (SELECT t2.transactionid
                      FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid AND
                          t2.status = 1
                 );

OR USING LEFT JOIN

SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.transactionid = t2.transactionid
WHERE t2.transactionid IS NULL